# Keeping alive PostedFile.InputStream (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

Maybe it's the worst practice in the world, but I was wondering wich's the best way to "keep alive" the InputStream of the FileUpload Control.

I would give you one example. Let's assume you have the FileUpload control in one WebForm, and you want process it in the next WebForm (after Response.Redirect).

It would be great (unless for the memory) to have something similar to:

```
Session["PostedFile"] = this.FileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream.
```

Unfortunately, this results in:

System.ObjectDisposedException

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a temp file and store the temp filename in the session?

Comment: Thanks Jonh. I just was trying to avoid that (I don't want temporal files left in the server), but maybe it's a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you read the stream first and then add it to the session?

Comment: Thanks!. Because of the cost of reading a very large image or file. In some way it's a work that has been done before by the framework but maybe it's the only solution.

Thanks again!